# Why such differences between Infopath 2010 templates for a Form Library and for a List?

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-library, digital-signature, sharepoint-workspace

Table 3 (Comparing form library and list templates) of msdn article [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961896.aspx) states that:

- support for **custom code** is available for a **Form Library Template** but not a **List template**
- **Infopath Filler** as **offline client** is available for Form Library template but only Sharepoint Workspace for a List Template
- **digital signatures** are available for a **Form Library Template** but not for a **List Template**

[image]

Why?

I'd like to understand under-the-hood things better for and before making decisions in selecting and using the right Infopath form template for my tasks.